# One Of My Favorite Rileys

Tags: riddle, word

> My Prefix can be a line
>
> But I am more known as a kind of formation
>
> My Infix is a very great waterfall
>
> Tourists usually take picture of it
>
> A great channel my Suffix is
>
> It may just be one of the best
>
> My whole is a very famous  person

**Note** :

> Title is also a hint

Hint :

> That person received many awards for what he/she made

Hint 2 :

> EDIT : A specific number can be related to this Riley Riddle

Hint 3 :

> The specific number is 7

Hint 4 :

> The name of the waterfall consists of just 3 letters

Comment: First thing to come to mind for the infix: Rot13(Avntnen Snyyf $\to$ AS)?

Comment: Nope not that one :D @user477343

Comment: "A great channel my Suffix is" is that referenced to Yoda from "Star wars"?

Comment: @NoOorZ24 Hmm, it could be :)

Comment: Not as famous, but could the infix be about ROT13(Qvrgna Snyyf)?

Comment: Nope not that @Cubemaster

Comment: Dang, there's a lot of waterfalls out there. Can we get a hint, maybe a general geographic location?

Comment: Hmm, you can I guess @Cubemaster

Comment: @Cubemaster That consists of more than three letters though

Comment: Alright..... ROT13(Jyv Snyyf(Tunan) be gur Qhs Snyyf(Znprqbavn))?

Comment: One of them is correct but I won't tell which one :D @Cubemaster

Comment: Good enough for me

Comment: Yep, hope you get the right answer :) @Cubemaster

Comment: Ooh I think i have it. I will add my reasoning in a bit, but is it ROT13(W.X. Ebjyvat)?

Comment: Hmm, how 'bout you post an answer first :D @Cubemaster

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Updated answer**

Could you be :

> Rowling? (Thanks to @El-Guest for suggesting I drop the "J.K.")

My Prefix can be a line

> A Row is generally a line

But I am more known as a kind of formation

> People row boats in formation?

My Infix is a very great waterfall

> The Wli Falls(in Ghana)

Tourists usually take pictures of it

> It is a popular waterfall to take pictures of

A great channel my Suffix is

> National Geographic (NG)

It might just be one of the best

> Sure, if you enjoy nature.

My whole is a very famous person

> (J.K.) Rowling, very famous for her Harry Potter books

Note :

Title is also a hint

Hint :

That person received many awards for what he/she made

> J.K. Rowling has won many an award for her books.

Hint 2 :

EDIT : A specific number can be related to this Riley Riddle

Hint 3 :

The specific number is 7

> Seven Harry Potter books

Comment: Dang this was a solid answer, especially with the row - line/formation thing

Comment: Yeah... I was really convinced of this one

Comment: Very super close yet quite far at the same time (Not the precise answer) :)

Comment: @KevinL Could it be just the last name, with prefix r13(ebj)? That’s a line and formation...

Comment: @El-Guest Oh, I didn't even think about that

Comment: you are probably right

Comment: I have no idea why it would be so far if this was right, but good luck!!

Comment: Indeed, this is the correct answer. Will give the checkmark and bounty tomorrow  :D

Comment: @El-Guest Yes that is what I meant. Nice! :)

Answer (score 3):

Partial:

> Is the waterfall Victoria Falls? which would imply the infix/middle name of the person is Vic/Victoria

Comment: Nope, that's not the one I had in mind

Answer (score 2):

Not so much a "Partial Answer" as a "guess based on your note"

Your claim:

> The title is a hint

That points me in the direction of

> "My Favorite Things"

from

> *The Sound of Music*

To be honest, I didn't even try the actual riddle; but I think I might have at least solved the hint.

Comment: hmm, I think that's still not it though :D

Comment: I didn't think it was the answer, but am I on the right track with the hint?

Comment: Well, it does relate to my favorite things but it's definitely not about music :D

Answer (score 2):

Might it be

> CHOW LING

Prefix

> not sure about the line but CHO formartion is for Chief Happiness Officer

Infix

> thank to @Cubemaster WLI The Wli Falls(in Ghana)

Suffix

> NG national geographic

Comment: Close but still wrong :D

Answer (score 1):

Since I think the answer @Cubemaster provided is correct, I'm not going to repeat it, but I think I know how his answer might relate to the title.

> In the Goblet of Fire, Harry Potter encounters a Sphinx in the maze which asks him a Riley Riddle. Is that one of your favorite Riley Riddles @Kevin ?

Comment: Nope not that :D

Comment: I just meant that I like (Answer)'s books very much